# Cmd window to close after opening process with .bat

Tags: batch-file, cmd, window, application-start

I'm new with batch file and the code I'm using I had to find but it always opens `cmd` but doesn't close it after the program is open. I'm aware that it doesn't close because it's a window process and `cmd` doesn't close until after the window is closed. I would like to to close after it opens the window.  Here is the code:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe" -Xmx1G -Xms1G -jar "Minecraft_Server.exe"
```

I've used many different ways close it like putting Exit at the end or putting `cmd /c` in front but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

The start command does not seem to work with multiple parameters.
Only solution I could come up with is creating a windowless executable that handles the executing with multiple parameters.


**Original answer**

I've tested the following and it works because Progra~1 is the a conversion of the Program files folder in oldskool 8 character style:

```
start c:\Progra~1\Intern~1\iexplore.exe -new -k "http://www.google.com/"
```

I cannot verify this because I do not have java, but it should work:

```
start C:\Program~1\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe -Xmx1G -Xms1G -jar "Minecraft_Server.exe"
```

However if more folders start with `Progra` then it could also be `Progra~2`, `Progra~3` etc. You would have to try what works.

Comment: thank you that worked i used start a couple of times but it would always says something like "Windows could not find -Xmx1G be sure you spelled it right" but thank you again

Comment: I don't think this answer would work.  "start" will choke on the multi parameters.

Comment: @djangofan You're right, I don't know why it worked then, but my only guess would be that google.com was my default browser page.